# Find three power series with the following properties

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series

Find three power series:

$\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n,\sum _{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n,\sum _{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$ such that the radius of convergence of the sum of the any two of the series is $0$ but the radius of convergence of the sum of all three series is $\infty$

Comment: For the convergence radius of the sum of two series to be zero it **must** be that one of the series has convergence radius of zero...

Comment: @DonAntonio..$a_n=n!,b_n=2 n!$ can you give third one

Comment: @suresh I don't think the conditions are posible: since $\;R(a_n+b_n)=R(a_n+c_n)=R(b_n+c_n)=0\;$, this means two of the series have convergence zero, say $\;\sum a_n,\,\sum b_n\;$, but then the sum $\;\sum(a_n+b_n+c_n)=\sum((a_n+b_n)+c_n)\;$ also has radius zero...But I may be missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a suggestion by *suresh*, take $a_n = n!$, $b_n = 2n!$, $c_n = -3n!$.

Comment: @Krish In what way does this not answer the question? It is an explicit gives an example of three power series satisfying the conditions in the OP's question. In what way does the statement "To critique or request clarification... " apply to this answer. Do you mean that my answer should be more fleshed out / explained? I personally think my answer, though very succinct, it is very clear and provides all necessary information in this context...